# XCode: How can I input javascript into UIWebView to click on a link (but the link is different each time)

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to click on a link in a webpage (which is always a different hyperlink but has the same text e.g. "Prev Day") with UIWebView. How can I do this once a UIButton is touched?

This is the HTML code (just of the link which needs to be clicked) of the webpage:

```
<tr><td><DIV align=center><A class=ROLLOVER href=" http://www.dhsb.org/index.phtml?d=201435&amp;de=0&amp;my_child_timetable_date=1322638827" t="e" v=" http://www.dhsb.org/index.phtml?d=201435&amp;de=0&amp;my_child_timetable_date=1322638827"><FONT size=2>Prev Day</FONT></A>
```

Maybe the UIWebView can look for the text "Prev Day" then look for a hyperlink associated with it and click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject javascript into the UIWebView to click the link, e.g.

```
var fonts = document.getElementsByTagName('font');
for(i=0;i<fonts.length;i++) {
  if (fonts[i].innerHTML == 'Prev Day') {
    fonts[i].parentNode.childNodes[0].click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately. Is there another way of doing this? :-)